# Spell Checker In TINYMCE Editor

Tags: php, tinymce, spell-checking

In my editor when i clicking on the spell checker it displays :

```
Please specify: spellchecker_rpc_url
```

This message displayed in alert box.

What is the reason?

Where should i set  spellchecker_rpc_url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    spellchecker_rpc_url: '/path/to/tiny_mce/plugins/spellchecker/rpc.php',
});
```